# Can I "trigger" media queries with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have multiple media queries that fire at 991px device width. Inside these queries, there are several hundred lines of CSS statements.

For a specific task, I want to trigger these queries without the need for a manual window resize.

Applying the css statements using .css() would be an option, if it were only a few statements. Unfortunately, this is not the case.

Is there a way to trigger the media queries without resizing the window?

Comment: In short, no. A simple workaround would be to duplicate those media queries and key them on a specific class on a common parent element. This will bloat up your CSS though.

Comment: Thank you, I consider doing it. Might be a bit laborious because those queries might get additional css statements, but at least it would work. With 'key them on a specific class', do you mean removing the media query from the copied css-set and adding the specific class in front of every statement? Or is there a media query statement that triggers the query only if a specific class exists? For example: @media(class: triggerThisQuery) {}

Answer (score 0):

in simple way when you are use Jquery you can add this statement to your code to be fired

```
$(window).resize()
```

Comment: This alone is not enough. You actually need to set the window to a size where the media query will be triggered. That's completely against the point of the question, and would be incredibly annoying for users